# Navigation bar covering over logo

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am fairly new to CSS and have a question I can't seem to figure out.  So I just started a MVC application and I am trying to float a logo over the navigation menu bar.  I got the logo into the position I want, but now the problem is that the navigation menu is covering over the top half of the logo.  Is there anyway I can choose for the logo to be on top of the bar?

This is  what my _Layout.cshtml looks like:

```
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: -50px;">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/IsabellasLogo.png" />   
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mission", "Mission", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu", "Menu", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy Isabellas's Pizzeria</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your navbar is set to have `navbar-fixed-top` class, which probably defines `position:fixed;`. Try changing this to `position:relative;`. You might need to also adjust margins, but without seeing actual CSS its hard to tell.

Another option would be to leave `position:fixed;` intact, but adjust `top:0` to something bigger, like `top:50px;`.